# Which one load images more efficient? WKWebview or UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Does anyone hear of using one WKWebView to display multiple images (around 50 images) is more efficient and saves memory than using UIImageView to load each image per UIImageView in one view controller?

If so. Why this solution can improve the performance? What's the difference between WKWebView and UIImageView when setting/displaying an image?

Comment: make it simple to use imageview because its made for showing images i guess ?

Comment: you can try pdfview to show images in order to reduce pressure, if you only have to show images. @Ray

Comment: Note that `UIImageView` is deprecated, Apple strongly recommends against using it. I wouldn't be suprised if they'll start rejecting apps that use `UIWebView`'s (if they don't already do it).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `UIImageView` and downsampling your images. One of my apps used to eat through my memory at 400 Mb when displaying a collection of images, now I'm at 80 tops.

Have a look at [Reducing Memory Footprint When Using UIImage](https://swiftsenpai.com/development/reduce-uiimage-memory-footprint/).

Comment: I tried this solution. The memory usage did decrease. After the comparison, I found out that using WKWebview to display multiple <img/> tags inside it which still has less memory usage than downsampling the UIImage. Moreover, the pictures don't have distortion problems in the WKWebView.