# SwiftUI: Memory leaking while fetching Image

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to display image from an URL inside my firebase document object.
The problem is after it got the `data`, the screen freeze until all of the image is loaded to the `UIImage`. And the memory used went from 150mb-ish to 1000mb-ish.

```
struct Card: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var question: String
    var answer: String
    var status: String
    var url: String
}
```

Here is the code I use to fetch Data

```
final class CardRepository: ObservableObject, CardRepositoryProtocol {
    
    private let store = Firestore.firestore()
    var resultSubject = CurrentValueSubject<[Card], Error>([])
    
    func get() {
        store.collection(StorageCollection.EnglishCard.getPath)
            .addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] snapshot, err in
                if let err = err {
                    resultSubject.send(completion: .failure(err))
                }
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    let cards = snapshot.documents.compactMap {
                        try? $0.data(as: Card.self)
                    }
                    resultSubject.send(cards)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

After get the result, I bind the data to `cards` inside `ViewModel`

```
class CardViewModel: CardViewModelProtocol, ObservableObject {
    
    internal var repository: CardRepositoryProtocol
    @Published private(set) var state: CardViewModelState = .loading
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    @Published var grid: [Int] = []
    @Published var cards: [Card] = []
    let numberOfColumn = 2
    
    required init (_ repository: CardRepositoryProtocol ) {
        self.repository = repository
        bindingCards()
        get()
    }
    
    
    private func bindingCards() {
        repository.resultSubject
            .sink { [unowned self] comp in
                switch comp {
                case .failure(let err):
                    self.state = .failed(err: err)
                case .finished:
                    print("finised")
                }
            } receiveValue: { [unowned self] res in
                self.state = .success(cards: res)
                cards = res
                getGrid(data: res)
            }.store(in: &cancellables)

    }
    
    private func getGrid(data: [Card]) {
        grid.removeAll()
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: data.count, by: numberOfColumn){
            
            if i != data.count{
                
                self.grid.append(i)
            }
            
        }
    }
```

In my `ContentView`, I create multiple `Item` (View) with `url` as a parameter

```
struct ContentView <ModelProtocol>: View where ModelProtocol: CardViewModelProtocol {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ModelProtocol
    var body: some View {
        switch viewModel.state {
        case .loading:
            ProgressView()
        case .failed(err: let err):
            Text(err.localizedDescription)
        case .success(cards: _):
            if viewModel.grid.count != 0 {
                
                //TopBard(viewModel: viewModel)
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    let cards = viewModel.cards
                    VStack(spacing: 10) {
                        ForEach(self.viewModel.grid, id: \.self) { i in
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                ForEach(i...(i + viewModel.numberOfColumn - 1), id: \.self) { j in
                                    if j != cards.count {
                                        Item(url:cards[j].url)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
struct Item: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader: ImageLoader
    @State var image: UIImage = UIImage()
    init (url: String) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader(urlString: url)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).foregroundColor(.green)
                    .frame(width: DeviceScreen.size.width/2 - 40, height: 200)
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: DeviceScreen.size.width/2 - 40, height: 200)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .onReceive(imageLoader.didChange) { data in
                        self.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? UIImage()
                    }
            }
            Button("Get Index") {
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I use this `ImageLoader` class to fetch `image` and send notify to `Item` to change the `Image`

```
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Data, Never>()
    var data = Data() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(data)
        }
    }
    
    init (urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = data
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what do you mean by *leak* here - how would you imagine display an image w/o creating it completely from data?

Comment: I know there is something wrong because the image size is about 2mb each and there were around 10-15 of them, while the memory used was around 700mb larger after the action. For the latter question, I'm not really sure the question

Comment: Memory usage doesn't depend on size as much as resolution, you need to downsample your images. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443565/13278922

Answer (score 1):

Using view model objects is known to cause memory leaks that why we use structs in SwiftUI. Your leak is on the line `imageLoader = ImageLoader(urlString: url)` you can't init objects inside `View` structs like that because the View struct hierarchy is created and thrown away every time there is a state change. The object either needs to be a singleton, e.g. `ImageLoader.shared` or you can use the `@StateObject` wrapper which will init it once, but you should really try to avoid using objects and instead use the `task` modifier or a struct that conforms to `DynamicProperty`.

Also, `ForEach` is a View struct not a for loop and you can't use `id: \.self` with it. You need to supply `ForEach` with `Identifiable` data or `id` can be a key path to a unique var within the data, it cannot be the data itself.