# high memory usage because of a large image showed in a sheet

Tags: swiftui

I want to demonstrate a large size image(5184*3456) in a modal sheet with swiftui.

When I popup the sheet, memory usage increases from 20mb up to 100mb. However, when I dismiss the sheet, memory usage just decreases from 100mb to 92mb. I popup the sheet again, memory usage increases from 92mb back to 100mb.

Back and forth, memory usage always changes between 92mb and 100mb, instead of between 20mb and 100mb that I expect to.

Why doesn't memory usage decrease to 20mb when the sheet dismiss? Why doesn't image been purged from memory when the sheet dismisses? I just want memory usage stays in a low level. How could I do?

```
struct IntroductionView: View {
    @Environment(\EnvironmentValues.presentationMode) var presentation
    var body: some View {
         GeometryReader{geo in
           VStack(alignment:.leading){
            Image("image")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(maxHeight:geo.size.height/4)
                .clipped()
                Spacer()
                Button(action: { 
                  presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Close")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: View with image is cached in memory for faster reload

Comment: @Asperi is there any way to release the image manually?In my case,  the view with the large image won't be used very often. So I want it not to be cached in memory.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443565/13278922